# How to not URL encode a route parameter?

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.4 with Java, and I've got this route:

```
GET /page/:slug controllers.Application.page(slug: String)
```

---

So, for instance, if `slug = this-is-a-slug`, there's no problem, the route looks like this:

```
/page/this-is-a-slug
```

---

But, if `slug = first-part-of-the-slug/second-part-of-the-slug`, the URL bar shows:

```
/page/first-part-of-the-slug%2Fsecond-part-of-the-slug
```

I'd like to avoid encoding the slug, knowing that the number of slug 'parts' is undefined, and keep the slug as a unique parameter.

How could I do that? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "*" like:

```
/page/*slug
```

Look for the "**Dynamic parts spanning several /**" section in the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRouting

> If you want a dynamic part to capture more than one URI path segment,
>   separated by forward slashes, you can define a dynamic part using the
>   * id syntax, which uses the .* regular expression:
>
> ```
> GET   /files/*name       controllers.Application.download(name)
> ```
>
> Here, for a request like `GET /files/images/logo.png`, the `name` dynamic
>   part will capture the `images/logo.png` value.